# C# start app with command-line parameters

Tags: c#, command-line, arguments

I have a small app(`C# WPF`) that starts automatically with system, but i want that main window of my program will not shown when it starts from autorun(with command-line parameter `autorun`).

I written this code:

```
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Args.Length == 0) 
            this.Run(new MainWindow());

        base.OnStartup(e);

    }
```

But it didn't work... So how i can check existence of my `autorun` parameter from `App.xaml.cs` and prevent opening `MainWindow`?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to attach a debugger and see why the window opens?

Comment: Window opens by dispatcher, and when i try to override event OnStartup i get exception: `InvalidOperationException`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find `StartupUri` attribute  at the top of your App.xaml file and remove it:

`override` the `OnStartup` as below

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    if (e.Args.Length == 0)
    {
        // no argument 
        // do stuff 
    }
    else
    {
        // with arguments
        // do stuff 
    }
    this.Shutdown();
}
```